# Hiding text from long strings to stop from making new lines

Tags: c#

I want to know if it is possible in C# to stop the console from making new lines from long strings and rather just hide the text that goes past the width of the window.

For example, when I make long strings, the result would be this:

```
Blah blah blah, word stuff, word stuff, bl | <-- Window width
ah blah blah.                              | <-- Window width
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Blah blah blah, word stuff, word stuff, bl | <-- Window width
                                           | <-- Window width
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by intercepting the `Console` standard output.

The code below is just to get you started. If you need to support tabs, random cursor positioning, mixtures of line endings (e.g. \r\n and \n and \r), then it may need more work.

`ConsoleTruncator` lets you define the "maxlinelength" which controls the max number of characters on each line - this doesn't stop wrapping happening if the console window width has been shrunk to below that "maxlinelength" value.

So instead, you could use something like this to "track" the width of the console (well close to):

```
bool bRoom = (Console.WindowWidth - 1 - m_columnposition) > 0;
```

For simple `Write`, and `WriteLines`, I think it should be ok.

A more advanced way of doing it would to be capture all console output, you would buffer and track it all, and would then rewrite it using `Console.SetCursorPosition` and `Console.Write`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    public class ConsoleTruncator : TextWriter
    {
        TextWriter m_console;

        int m_maxlinelength;
        int m_columnposition;

        public ConsoleTruncator(int maxlinelength)
        {
            m_maxlinelength = maxlinelength;

            m_console = Console.Out; // save console stream reference between we replace it

            Console.SetOut(this); // redirect console to this TextWriter

            // (don't do the `SetOut` here ... you need to separate out the
            // the attach and detach of the custom `TextWriter` to the
            // console into some other utility class/helper...for good structure)
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get
            {
                return Encoding.UTF8;
            }
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            if (value == '\r')
                return;

            if (value == '\n')
            {
                OutputChar(value);

                m_columnposition = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                bool bRoom = (m_maxlinelength - m_columnposition) > 0;

                if (bRoom)
                {
                    OutputChar(value);

                    m_columnposition++;
                }
            }

        }

        private void OutputChar(char value)
        { 
            m_console.Write(value);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] somelines =
            {
                "AAALorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam auctor neque quis euismod auctor. Fusce massa nibh, fringilla eu mi ornare, ullamcorper tristique nibh. Aenean eget neque111",
                "BBBxxxxxxxx vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx222",
                "CCCNullam porta eu magna eget rutrum. Aenean orci urna, pretium ut odio vitae, euismod rhoncus ligula. Vivamus condimentum semper lacus id tempor. Phasellus at turpis a quam ornare tincidunt. Vivamus eleifend quam eget velit porttitor, sit amet laoreet risus consectetur. Mauris eu arcu sit amet ipsum vulputate porttitor. Phasellus elementum erat eu blandit semper. Integer eu metus urna. Pellentesque at posuere purus. Nu333",
                "0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 0123456789\r\n0123456789+*+*+*+*+*0123456789+*+*+*+*+*0123456789",
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\r\n\r\nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
            };

            using (var consoleTruncator = new ConsoleTruncator(40))
            {
                foreach(string s in somelines)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("write a bit");
                Console.Write("-write a bit more");
                Console.Write("-write too muchhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use buffsize, like this:

```
int windowWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
string str = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
Console.Write(str.ToCharArray(), 0, windowWidth);
```

Another way is DIY. It's a little difficult to do so, but you can do it with following steps:
1. Get the current window size

```
int windowWidth = Console.WindowWidth;
```

2. Get the current string's display length, it's related with your font

```
Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 11);
var size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, font).Width;
```

3. Use the 2 values to cut the string & show the 1st part.

But it's very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adjusting the Screen Buffer Size Width of the Console Window:

[image]

To adjust it programmatically, you can call:

```
 //Any value greater than 80:
 Console.BufferWidth = 120;
```

Comment: I doubt this will stop automatic wrapping for long lines... (indeed it will hide *some* text by adding horizontal scroll, but it may not be what OP is looking for)